# How to convert colon notation duration time if we have more than 60 minutes

Tags: r, duration, difftime

I am stuck with something simple: I have vector of minutes and seconds like, e.g., `myvec=c("10:56","2:32","0:00","0:00","62:59","60:40","46:23")`. Here the number before the `:` notes the minutes and after the colon we have the seconds.

I tried

```
difftime(myvec,format='%M:%S')
Error in difftime(myvec, format = "%M:%S") : 
  unused argument (format = "%M:%S")
```

however my problem seems to be that some minutes values are bigger than 60. I am a bit startled that I can't think of any straightforward solution. Maybe I just misunderstood the `difftime` documentation. Sorry if this creates a duplicate.

EDIT:

Since some people asked:

```
as.difftime(myvec,format='%M:%S',units='mins')
10.933333  2.533333  0.000000  0.000000        NA        NA 46.383333
```

Instead of the two NAs I want the command to return something like `62.9999 60.6666`. At this point I am just curious whether there is any solution without using regex.

Comment: Does using `as.difftime(myvec,format='%M:%S')` help?

Comment: yeah that returns the desired result, but creates two `NAs` where the minutes are bigger than 60

Comment: Based upon `strptime` description, there is no option to allow for > 60 minutes

Comment: @CIAndrews +1. Seems like the answer is that you have to use regex-methods to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  Except for (2) they use no packages.

**1) sub** Extract the numbers, convert to numeric and compute the seconds.

```
60 * as.numeric(sub(":.*", "", myvec)) + as.numeric(sub(".*:", "", myvec))
## [1]  656  152    0    0 3779 3640 2783
```

**2) strapply** We could also use `strapply` in gsubfn:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(myvec, "(.+):(.+)", ~ 60 * as.numeric(min) + as.numeric(sec), simplify = TRUE)
## [1]  656  152    0    0 3779 3640 2783
```

**3) scan** Another solution can be based on scan and matrix multiplication:

```
c(c(60, 1) %*% matrix(scan(text = myvec, sep = ":", quiet = TRUE), 2))
## [1]  656  152    0    0 3779 3640 2783
```

**4) eval** `eval` has a bad reputation but if you don't mind using it then it is the shortest of the solutions here.

```
sapply(parse(text = paste0("60*", sub(":", "+", myvec))), eval)
## [1]  656  152    0    0 3779 3640 2783
```

Comment: nice solution, thanks. I was actually thinking of using an older regex post from you to solve this. I am a bit baffled that R time functions have such problems with the minutes being bigger than 60.